# A question about $\frac{a}{b} \le \frac{a +c}{b+d} \le \frac{c}{d}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is an exercise from Beckenbach and Bellman. (There is one downvoted version of this, which I will not link.)

> Show that if $\frac{a}{b} \le \frac{c}{d} $ with $b$ and $d$ positive, then $\frac{a}{b} \le \frac{a +c}{b+d} \le \frac{c}{d} $ and that the sign of equality holds if and only if $ad = bc$

The hint "Intermediate steps" essentially splits up and rewrites the inequality into 2 parts.

> $\frac{a +c}{b+d} - \frac{a}{b}  = \frac{bc - ad}{b(b+d)} \ge 0$ And $\frac{c}{d} - \frac{a +c}{b+d}   = \frac{bc - ad}{d(b+d)} \ge 0$

So, I see how he has rewritten the inequality in terms of eg, if $p \ge q$ then $p - q \ge 0$
So, a few questions.

(i) Could I get a good hint at how to proceed?
(ii) What is the logic of using what one has to show/prove by simply rewriting it as part of that solution. Maybe the final step will answer it, but  I guess I am trying to discern the logic of the author.

**Addendum**
Taking into account the comments below, I am presenting a solution based on "cross multiplication".

Given: $\frac{a}{b} \le \frac{c}{d} \iff ad \le bc$

$a(b+d) = ab + ad \le bc + ab = b(a + c) $

$\implies a\cdot b^{-1}(b+d)(b+d)^{-1}  \le  b\cdot b^{-1}(a + c)(b+d)^{-1} $

$ \implies\frac{a}{b}  \le  \frac {a + c}{b+d}$

Now:

$c(b+d) =  cd + bc\ge ad + cd = d(a + c) $

$\implies c\cdot d^{-1}(b+d)\cdot(b+d)^{-1}  \ge  d\cdot d^{-1}(a + c)\cdot (b+d)^{-1}$

$\implies \frac {c}{d}  \ge  \frac {a + c}{b+d}$

Thus, in conclusion, by transivity

$\frac {a}{b}  \le  \frac {a + c}{b+d} \le \frac {c}{d}$

**Conclusion and Question.**
As poor as the solution might be based on the hint provided by Beckenbach and Bellman, it would still be interesting to compare the two approaches. So far, I am unable to complete their solution using their hints.

Comment: Although your approach may be workable, there is a much easier way.  Cross multiplication is your friend.  Assuming that $r,s,t,u > 0$, you have that $~\displaystyle \frac{r}{s} < \frac{t}{u} \iff ru < st.$

Comment: I agree with @user2661923 It is  a bad hint.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. Thanks for your input. I do understand your answer at it being a bad hint and the recommendation to cross multiply, but even working through a bad hint can be quite informative. So I would still like to understand his approach, even if doing so informs me how not to do it.